# How to setup rule in .htacces to remove two sub directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have setup .htaccess to rewrite some rules in our system and they are all working fine.
Howevever, i am having trouble with the following rule. Can anyone help with this?

I have the following URL
`test.com/admin/page/files/TEMPFILES/file.pdf`

I would like this to be redirected if the url contains the following two strings `"/admin/page/" AND "TEMPFILES"`

i would like this to redirect to the following
`test.com/files/TEMPFILES/file.pdf`

I have tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^TEMPFILES
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin/([a-z]+)(/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ $2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Following URL

`test.com/admin/page/files/TEMPFILES/file.pdf`

should redirect to

`test.com/files/TEMPFILES/file.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/page/files/TEMPFILES/(.+)\.pdf$
RewriteRule (.*) /files/TEMPFILES/%1.pdf [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `/admin/page/files/TEMPFILES/foobar.pdf` to `/files/TEMPFILES/foobar.pdf` .